# AVR32 UC3C USART interrupt based

Tags: c, usart, avr32

I am trying to communicate using USART(rs232) over AVR32 UC3C. I have followed the sample given on link - http://simplemachines.it/martin/mizar32/1.6.0-AT32UC3/DRIVERS/INTC/EXAMPLE/interrupt_usart_example.c.

```
/* This source file is part of the ATMEL AVR32-UC3-SoftwareFramework-1.6.0 Release */

/*This file is prepared for Doxygen automatic documentation generation.*/
/*! \file *********************************************************************
 *
 * \brief Example of an interrupt-driven USART communication.
 *
 * This file contains an example using the USART module with interrupts.
 *
 * It will display a string on the screen. Refer to the usart_options structure
 * in main for configuration options for your terminal.
 *
 * Please make sure that the correct jumper(s) is/are set on your development
 * board. Refer to your hardware reference guide if necessary.
 *
 * - Compiler:           IAR EWAVR32 and GNU GCC for AVR32
 * - Supported devices:  All AVR32 devices with an INTC module can be used.
 * - AppNote:
 *
 * \author               Atmel Corporation: http://www.atmel.com \n
 *                       Support and FAQ: http://support.atmel.no/
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

/*! \page License
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Atmel Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 * list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 * and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * 3. The name of Atmel may not be used to endorse or promote products derived
 * from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * 4. This software may only be redistributed and used in connection with an Atmel
 * AVR product.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY ATMEL "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT ARE
 * EXPRESSLY AND SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL ATMEL BE LIABLE FOR
 * ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE
 *
 */

/*! \mainpage
 * \section intro Introduction
 * This is the documentation for the data structures, functions, variables,
 * defines, enums, and typedefs for the interrupt controller driver. It also
 * comes bundled with a basic application as an example of usage.
 *
 * This example demonstrates how to use the INTC driver for the USART RXRDY
 * interrupt.
 *
 * Operating mode: each character typed on the PC terminal is echoed back.
 *
 * \note The IAR built-in event handling mechanism manages interrupt groups but
 * not lines. This example shows how to register an interrupt through the INTC
 * driver, which manages lines. If interrupt request lines do not have to be
 * handled separately within groups, then the IAR built-in event handling
 * mechanism can be used in this way:
 *   - remove the INTC driver files (intc.c and exception.s82) from the IAR
 *     project;
 *   - remove calls to the INTC driver functions (\ref INTC_init_interrupts and
 *     \ref INTC_register_interrupt);
 *   - add <tt>\#pragma handler = \e AVR32_xxxx_IRQ_GROUP, \e int_level</tt>
 *     above the \c __interrupt keyword;
 *   - the IAR project options can be changed to catch unhandled events under
 *     the \e Runtime tab of the <i>General Options</i> item.
 *
 * \warning The IAR built-in event handling mechanism
 *          (<tt>\#pragma exception</tt> and <tt>\#pragma handler</tt>) MUST NOT
 *          be used along with the INTC driver within a project.
 *
 * \section files Main Files
 *   - intc.c: interrupt controller driver;
 *   - intc.h: interrupt controller driver header file;
 *   - exception.S: exception and interrupt handlers assembly file for GCC;
 *   - interrupt_usart_example.c: interrupt controller example application.
 *
 * \section compilinfo Compilation Information
 * This software is written for GNU GCC for AVR32 and for IAR Embedded Workbench
 * for Atmel AVR32. Other compilers may or may not work.
 *
 * \section deviceinfo Device Information
 * All AVR32 devices with an INTC and a USART module can be used.
 *
 * \section configinfo Configuration Information
 * This example has been tested with the following configuration:
 *   - EVK1100, EVK1101, EVK1103, EVK1104, EVK1105, AT32UC3L-EK evaluation kits; STK600+RCUC3L routing card
 *   - CPU clock: 
 *        -- 12 MHz : EVK1100, EVK1101, EVK1104, EVK1105, AT32UC3L-EK evaluation kits; STK600+RCUC3L routing card;
 *        -- 16 Mhz : UC3C_EK 
 *   - USART0 (on EVK1100) or USART1 (on EVK1101 or STK1000) connected to a PC
 *     serial port via a standard RS232 DB9 cable, or USART0 (on EVK1105) or
 *     USART1 (on EVK1104) or USART2 (on EVK1103) or USART3 (on AT32UC3L-EK) abstracted
 *     with a USB CDC connection to a PC;
 *   - PC terminal settings:
 *     - 57600 bps (on EVK1100, EVK1101, AT32UC3C-EK, EVK1104, EVK1105, AT32UC3L-EK) or 115200 bps (on
 *       STK1000),
 *     - 8 data bits,
 *     - no parity bit,
 *     - 1 stop bit,
 *     - no flow control.
 *
 * \section contactinfo Contact Information
 * For further information, visit
 * <A href="http://www.atmel.com/products/AVR32/">Atmel AVR32</A>.\n
 * Support and FAQ: http://support.atmel.no/
 */


#include <avr32/io.h>
#include "compiler.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "print_funcs.h"
#include "intc.h"
#if defined (__GNUC__)
#  if   defined (__AVR32_AP7000__)
#    include "pm_at32ap7000.h"
#  else
#    include "power_clocks_lib.h"
#  endif
#elif defined (__ICCAVR32__) || defined (__AAVR32__)
#  if  defined (__AT32AP7000__)
#    include "pm_at32ap7000.h"
#  else
#    include "power_clocks_lib.h"
#  endif
#endif
#include "gpio.h"
#include "usart.h"


/*! \name USART Settings
 */
//! @{
#if BOARD == EVK1100
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART0)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART0_RXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART0_RXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART0_TXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART0_TXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART0_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == EVK1101
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART1)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART1_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == UC3C_EK
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART2)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART2_RXD_0_1_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART2_RXD_0_1_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART2_TXD_0_1_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART2_TXD_0_1_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART2_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == EVK1104
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART1)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART1_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == EVK1105
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART0)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART0_RXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART0_RXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART0_TXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART0_TXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART0_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == STK1000
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART1)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART1_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        115200
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == NGW100
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART1)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART1_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        115200
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == STK600_RCUC3L0
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART1)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_1_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_RXD_0_1_FUNCTION
// For the RX pin, connect STK600.PORTE.PE3 to STK600.RS232 SPARE.RXD
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_1_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART1_TXD_0_1_FUNCTION
// For the TX pin, connect STK600.PORTE.PE2 to STK600.RS232 SPARE.TXD
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART1_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ FOSC0  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
#elif BOARD == UC3L_EK
#  define EXAMPLE_USART                 (&AVR32_USART3)
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN          AVR32_USART3_RXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART3_RXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN          AVR32_USART3_TXD_0_0_PIN
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION     AVR32_USART3_TXD_0_0_FUNCTION
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ             AVR32_USART3_IRQ
#  define EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE        57600
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_DFLL_FREQ_HZ   96000000  // DFLL target frequency, in Hz
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_MCUCLK_FREQ_HZ 12000000  // MCU clock target frequency, in Hz
#  undef  EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ
#  define EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ 12000000  // PBA clock target frequency, in Hz
    /*! \name Parameters to pcl_configure_clocks().
     */
    //! @{
    static scif_gclk_opt_t gc_dfllif_ref_opt = { SCIF_GCCTRL_SLOWCLOCK, 0, OFF };
    static pcl_freq_param_t pcl_dfll_freq_param =
    {
      .main_clk_src = PCL_MC_DFLL0,
      .cpu_f        = EXAMPLE_TARGET_MCUCLK_FREQ_HZ,
      .pba_f        = EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ,
      .pbb_f        = EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ,
      .dfll_f       = EXAMPLE_TARGET_DFLL_FREQ_HZ,
      .pextra_params = &gc_dfllif_ref_opt
    };
    //! @}
#endif
//! @}


/*! \brief The USART interrupt handler.
 *
 * \note The `__attribute__((__interrupt__))' (under GNU GCC for AVR32) and
 *       `__interrupt' (under IAR Embedded Workbench for Atmel AVR32) C function
 *       attributes are used to manage the `rete' instruction.
 */
#if defined (__GNUC__)
__attribute__((__interrupt__))
#elif defined(__ICCAVR32__)
__interrupt
#endif
static void usart_int_handler(void)
{
  int c;

  // In the code line below, the interrupt priority level does not need to be
  // explicitly masked as it is already because we are within the interrupt
  // handler.
  // The USART Rx interrupt flag is cleared by side effect when reading the
  // received character.
  // Waiting until the interrupt has actually been cleared is here useless as
  // the call to usart_write_char will take enough time for this before the
  // interrupt handler is leaved and the interrupt priority level is unmasked by
  // the CPU.
  usart_read_char(EXAMPLE_USART, &c);

  // Print the received character to USART.
  // It is a simple echo, so there will be no translation of '\r' to "\r\n". The
  // connected terminal has to be configured accordingly to send '\n' after
  // '\r'.
  usart_write_char(EXAMPLE_USART, c);
}


/*! \brief The main function.
 *
 * It sets up the USART module on EXAMPLE_USART. The terminal settings are 57600
 * 8N1.
 * Then it sets up the interrupt handler and waits for a USART interrupt to
 * trigger.
 */
int main(void)
{
  static const gpio_map_t USART_GPIO_MAP =
  {
    {EXAMPLE_USART_RX_PIN, EXAMPLE_USART_RX_FUNCTION},
    {EXAMPLE_USART_TX_PIN, EXAMPLE_USART_TX_FUNCTION}
  };

  // USART options.
  static const usart_options_t USART_OPTIONS =
  {
    .baudrate     = EXAMPLE_USART_BAUDRATE,
    .charlength   = 8,
    .paritytype   = USART_NO_PARITY,
    .stopbits     = USART_1_STOPBIT,
    .channelmode  = USART_NORMAL_CHMODE
  };

#if BOARD == EVK1100 || BOARD == EVK1101 || BOARD == UC3C_EK || BOARD == EVK1104 || BOARD == EVK1105 || BOARD == STK600_RCUC3L0

  // Configure Osc0 in crystal mode (i.e. use of an external crystal source, with
  // frequency FOSC0) with an appropriate startup time then switch the main clock
  // source to Osc0.
  pcl_switch_to_osc(PCL_OSC0, FOSC0, OSC0_STARTUP);

#elif BOARD == STK1000
  pm_reset();
#elif BOARD == UC3L_EK
  // Note: on the AT32UC3L-EK board, there is no crystal/external clock connected
  // to the OSC0 pinout XIN0/XOUT0. We shall then program the DFLL and switch the
  // main clock source to the DFLL.
  pcl_configure_clocks(&pcl_dfll_freq_param);
  // Note: since it is dynamically computing the appropriate field values of the
  // configuration registers from the parameters structure, this function is not
  // optimal in terms of code size. For a code size optimal solution, it is better
  // to create a new function from pcl_configure_clocks_dfll0() and modify it
  // to use preprocessor computation from pre-defined target frequencies.
#endif

  // Assign GPIO to USART.
  gpio_enable_module(USART_GPIO_MAP,
                     sizeof(USART_GPIO_MAP) / sizeof(USART_GPIO_MAP[0]));

  // Initialize USART in RS232 mode.
  usart_init_rs232(EXAMPLE_USART, &USART_OPTIONS, EXAMPLE_TARGET_PBACLK_FREQ_HZ);
  print(EXAMPLE_USART, ".: Using interrupts with the USART :.\n\n");

  // Disable all interrupts.
  Disable_global_interrupt();

  // Initialize interrupt vectors.
  INTC_init_interrupts();

  // Register the USART interrupt handler to the interrupt controller.
  // usart_int_handler is the interrupt handler to register.
  // EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ is the IRQ of the interrupt handler to register.
  // AVR32_INTC_INT0 is the interrupt priority level to assign to the group of
  // this IRQ.
  // void INTC_register_interrupt(__int_handler handler, unsigned int irq, unsigned int int_level);
  INTC_register_interrupt(&usart_int_handler, EXAMPLE_USART_IRQ, AVR32_INTC_INT0);

  // Enable USART Rx interrupt.
  EXAMPLE_USART->ier = AVR32_USART_IER_RXRDY_MASK;
  print(EXAMPLE_USART, "Type a character to use the interrupt handler.\n"
                       "It will show up on your screen.\n\n");

  // Enable all interrupts.
  Enable_global_interrupt();

  // We have nothing left to do in the main, so we may switch to a device sleep
  // mode: we just need to be sure that the USART module will be still be active
  // in the chosen sleep mode. The sleep mode to use is the FROZEN sleep mode:
  // in this mode the PB clocks are still active (so the USART module which is
  // on the Peripheral Bus will still be active while the CPU and HSB will be
  // stopped).
  // --
  // Modules communicating with external circuits should normally be disabled
  // before entering a sleep mode that will stop the module operation: this is not
  // the case for the FROZEN sleep mode.
  // --
  // When the USART interrupt occurs, this will wake the CPU up which will then
  // execute the interrupt handler code then come back to the while(1) loop below
  // to execute the sleep instruction again.

  while(1)
  {
    // If there is a chance that any PB write operations are incomplete, the CPU
    // should perform a read operation from any register on the PB bus before
    // executing the sleep instruction.
    AVR32_INTC.ipr[0];  // Dummy read

    // Go to FROZEN sleep mode.
    SLEEP(AVR32_PM_SMODE_FROZEN);
    // When the device wakes up due to an interrupt, once the interrupt is serviced,
    // go back into FROZEN sleep mode.
  }
}
```

**It has enabled my USART as well as the interrupts, but I am getting interrupts continuously without any data transfer from the other module.** I have been told there that `usart_read_char()` function will clear the interrupt status bit.

It will be good if anyone guides me here. Does anyone have the working sample code for UART?

Comment: It would be better to include your code in your question instead of asking SO users to download your code file. That would also make it easy to add comments to the code and point out where things are working and where they're not.

Comment: just a silly question but have you cross linked TX and RX ? have you check if you are also outputing something ? (via oscilloscope or by 2 anti-parallel LEDs) you need to have set the correct board,chip macros. proper clocks started, GPIO module and pins configured ... etc ... if your RX/TX pins are set as GPIO then their are not  connected to serial port ....

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/usart-rx-interrupts-at32uc3c0

The usart_read_char() does NOT clear the status flag if there has been an error (overrun, frame or parity error), i.e. if `usart_read_char() == USART_RX_ERROR`. In this case you need to reset the status bit yourself by writing `usart_reset_status(YOUR_USART);`

so something like

```
if (usart_read_char(YOUR_USART, character) == USART_RX_ERROR) {
      usart_reset_status(YOUR_USART);
} else {
    //Handle the character read here
}
```

The discussion linked above offers some more advice.